# Can't connect to docker published port for tftp

Tags: docker, portforwarding, tftp

i'm desperately trying to run tftp-hpa in a docker container. I built an image from dockerfile and start it with:

`docker run -v /tmp:/srv/tftp -d -p 69:69/udp -t tftp_server`

It's up and running and i can access the server via the virtual docker interface:

```
me@hostmachine$ tftp 172.17.0.79
tftp> get /srv/tftp/test
Received 7 bytes in 0.0 seconds
```

But from my opinion the -p 69:69/udp switch should forward the 69 port of my host machine to the containers port 69. But this does not seem to work:

```
me@hostmachine$ tftp localhost
tftp> get /srv/tftp/test
Transfer timed out.
```

From netstat, i see that port 69 on my hostmachine is open.
I tried exactly the same scenario with an httpd server and port 80. It works here, i can access the website via 127.0.0.1:80 in my browser.
The host machine is ubuntu 15.04 intel and the docker image is based on debian base image.

Can anybody help me? Is there something i could have missed? Any ideas how to debug? I will happily share my Dockerfile or any more information, but tried to keep question short.

Comment: Is your problem something similar to this? http://serverfault.com/questions/599101/tftpd-allows-connections-but-times-out-transferring-a-file

Comment: make sure tfpt doesn't bind to localhost but all interfaces (0.0.0.0)

Comment: @milan The tftp server is indeed bound to all interfaces.. Otherwise i would not be able to connect to its docker interface at 172.17.0.79.

Comment: @Viswesn no not really, he's running virtualbox and apparently the problem was with starting as service and standalone. I just checked my configuration and it's only started as standalone in foreground. I don't have anything else running (like xinetd) in my container

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your Docker container's network mode to "host".

i.e.
1) if you're running your container using "docker run" then append option "net=host"
2) if you're running using docker-compose, then under the tftp service definition block, add line "network-mode=host"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using boot2docker? If yes, then make sure that UDP port forwarding is enabled in your VirtualBox configuration. For example on the Mac console:

```
for i in {10000..10999}; do
    VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port$i,tcp,,$i,,$i";
    VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "udp-port$i,udp,,$i,,$i";
done
```

In the past there were [several boot2docker UDP issues](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4007) reported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no the host machine is ubuntu 15.04 64 bit native without any virtualbox. This seems to be a common problem, but not for me :/